# If a.b.c,d are rationals and x is irrational number, then prove that $\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$ is usually a irrational number. When do exceptions occur?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

If a.b.c,d are rationals and x is irrational number, then prove that $\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$ is usually a irrational number. When do exceptions occur?

This is a homework Question. i did this by assuming that given fraction is rational say $\frac{p}{q}$. Now i write $$\frac{ax+b}{cx+d} = \frac{p}{q}$$. After cross multiplying i get

$$\frac{qb-pd}{pc-qa}=x$$

So this contradiction as right hand side is rational and left hand side is irrational.
Now the question asks where does exceptions occur. I see that exceptions can occur when $a=c=0$ and $a=b=c=d$. But what are other exceptions and is my working method correct?

Thanks

Comment: How do I prove a number is **usually** irrational?

Comment: How did you cross multiply? I got lost :(

Comment: If $a=c$ and $b=d$, then the fraction is one and therefore rational. Similarly if $a=kc$ and $b=kd$ for some rational $k$

Comment: This is not really a proof by contradiction, but a proof by contrapositive.

Comment: Exceptions occur when $\,pc = qa\,$ so $\,ax\!+\!b = p/q(cx\!+\!d)\,$ for all $x$ since $\, (a,b) = p/q(c,d),\,$ i.e. the prior expressions are equal  polynomials.

Comment: @Bernard How ??

Comment: @BillDubuque what is (a,b)

Comment: @Gandi A pair of numbers, so $\,(a,b) = (c,d)\, $ means $\,a=c, b = d,\,$ and $\,n(a,b) = (na,nb).\ $

Comment: @BillDubuque i did not understand clearly what u say.

Comment: @Gandhi Precisely *what* is not clear?

Comment: @BillDubuque These are the exceptions I mentioned in my comment.

Comment: @smcc How did you chose $a=kc$ and b=kd?

Comment: @Gandhi That is implicit in my comment, i.e. it is when the denominator vanishes in your solution, i.e. when $\,pc - qa = 0\,$ (the "exception" is  division by zero).

Comment: @BillDubuque so $k=\frac{p}{q}$ and a=kc but how did u chose b?

Comment: @Gandhi you choose the coefficients so the the numerator polynomial is a rational multiple (here $p/q$) of the denominator polynomial, as I said in my first comment.

Comment: @BillDubuque Now i got it. You see  i am weak in English. Thanks anyways

Comment: To prove that (in general) if $x$ is irrational, $ax+b/cx+d$ is irrational, i.r. to prove  $P\implies Q$, you ˆprove that if $ax+b/cx+d$ is rational, then$x$ is rational ($\text{not}\,Q\implies \text{not}\,P$ – contrapositive), and you pretend it's  a proof by contradiction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The criterion is the following: If $ad-bc\ne0$ and $x\notin{\mathbb Q}$ then $$y:={ax+b\over cx+d}$$ is irrational as well, but if $ad-bc=0$ then $y$ is rational, or undefined.

*Proof.* Assume $c\ne0$. Then $cx+d$ is irrational, hence $\ne0$, and we may write
$$y={a\over c}-{ad-bc\over c(cx+d)}\ .$$
If $ad-bc\ne0$ then the last fraction, and therewith $y$, is irrational. If $ad-bc=0$ then $y={a\over c}$ is rational.

The case $c=0$ is even simpler: If $d=0$ as well then $y$ is undefined. If $d\ne0$ then $ad-bc\ne0$ means $a\ne0$. Therefore
$$y={a\over d}x+{b\over d}$$
is irrational if $ad-bc\ne0$, and is $={b\over d}$, if $ad-bc=0$.

Comment: What i have done by cross multiplication, is that correct?

Comment: @Gathdi: When doing cross multiplication with variables one has to make sure (by considering cases) that one is not multiplying by zero.